# Python não insere dados em sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite3

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sqlite3

app = '/backup/app/'
bd = app + 'bd/'
contato_banco = bd + 'contato.db'
contato_tab = (('nome' , 'TEXT'), ('email' , 'TEXT'), ('whatsapp' , 'INT'), ('mensagem' , 'TEXT'))
c = 'Enio', 'eniocsj@gmail.com', '+5513991874221', 'Alguma coisa'

def conexão(banco, comando):
    conexao = sqlite3.connect(bd + banco)
    cursor = conexao.cursor()
    return(cursor.execute(comando))

def cria_tabela(bd, tabela, campos):
    campo = ''
    for unidade in range(0, len(campos)):
        campo += '"' + campos[unidade][0] + '" ' + campos[unidade][1] + ', '
    return(conexão(bd, f'CREATE TABLE {tabela} ({campo[:-2]})'))

def insere_dado(banco, tabela, dados):
    global conexao, cursor
    saida = ''
    for campo in dados:
        saida += '"' + campo + '", '
    comando = (f'INSERT INTO {tabela} VALUES ({saida[:-2]})')
    conexão(banco, comando)
    sqlite3.connect(banco).commit()

insere_dado('teste.db', 'contato', c)
```

O python não me apresenta erro algum, no entanto não salva na tabela.

Comment: O banco `/backup/app/bd/teste` existe?

Comment: sqlite3.connect(bd + banco)  # cria o banco, caso não exista

Comment: A função cria_tabela() funciona perfetamente também.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faltou o `commit` para salvar as mudanças no banco.

```
...
result = cursor.execute(comando)
conexao.commit()  # Salvar
return result
```